# Setting file permissions (image for wallpaper use)

Tags: permissions, files, desktop-background

I have a dual boot Win7 & Ubuntu 16.04 set up.
I'm struggling with setting the wallpaper on Ubuntu. I have copied a .jpg image from the Windows drive into my Ubuntu pictures folder, and when I select it as wallpaper it works fine, but on reboot it's gone.

I have done some research, it appears I
should change file permissions to 'execute', this is what I've tried, and the errors I got back:

```
$ sudo chmod +x /home/showtown/pictures/DSC04787.jpg
[sudo] password for showtown:
chmod: cannot access '/home/showtown/pictures/DSC04787.jpg': No such file or directory

$ sudo chmod +x /DSC04787.jpg
chmod: cannot access '/DSC04787.jpg': No such file or directory
```

Am I missing something with syntax? I have used the full file path and just the file name.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Paths on Linux are case sensitive. This means that `Foo` is not the same as `foo`. The "pictures" directory is actually called `Pictures`, not `pictures` so that's why your first command failed. The second failed because you told it to look for a file called `DSC04787.jpg` in the root directory (`/`).

Also, there is absolutely no reason to use `sudo` here. The file should be owned by your regular user so that user should be able to change the permissions. So, the command you were looking for was:

```
chmod +x /home/showtown/Pictures/DSC04787.jpg
```

However, **there is absolutely no reason to make that image executable**. Please post a new question explaining i) what desktop environment you use (this is called "Unity" if you are using the default Ubuntu); ii) exactly how you set the wallpaper (using what tool, clicking where, selecting what etc).

I see no reason why it shouldn't survive a reboot but setting the image to executable will not solve it.

Comment: Hi thanks for getting back to me, I mentioned that I had searched to solve the problem, I do find that the professionals tend to assume that everyone understands syntax, every professional has a different way of solving  problems, thank you for helping me out, Just booted and there it is my image as a background/wallpaper. done nothing different, after all the errors something worked, I suspect the full path. My intention is to ditch windows, (a lost cause), install an ssd  and run linux as my sole operating system, just getting the feel at mo

Comment: @DavidMargison I am 100% sure that making the image executable didn't help. I don't know what you mean about professionals, just bear in mind that Linxu is case sensitive so write commands *exactly* as you see them. Spaces matter. CaSe matters. Anyway, if this answer helped you, please take a moment and [accept it](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Thanks for the advice I am new to this,  I do appreciate your help